# Android Collapsing toolbar background color when not collapsed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my application I have collapsing toolbar with image header. When the toolbar is in not-collapsed state ( when header is visible), the icons on toolbar are not clearly visible due to white color of header image. So how can I change the toolbar color in not-collapsed state to semi transparent black.

I know that for changing background color in collapsed state we use :- ContentScrim.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create scrim.xml by yourself and put it into your Toolbar between background ImageView and title TextView using FrameLayout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
     >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background_img"
            android:scaleType="center"
            />
        <View android:background="@drawable/scrim"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Your Title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And create res/drawable/scrim.xml (Please adjust alpha darkness to your need).

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:centerColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="#4d000000"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```